# Add item to nested dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am trying to add an item within a nested dictionary using a for loop. The item should be in the inner dictionary, so it shows up as an item after the item `'Aggressive': True`, and is in each one of the inner dictionaries, i.e. `'Gold-crested Toucan'` and `'Pearlescent Kingfisher'`.

```
rarebirds = {
    'Gold-crested Toucan': {
        'Height (m)': 1.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 35,
        'Aggressive': True},
    'Pearlescent Kingfisher': {
        'Height (m)': 0.25,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Aggressive': False},
}
#my most recent attempt below, although I've tried using .update as well as i and j dics within the loop

for key in rarebirds:
    rarebirds[key]['Seen'] == False
```

The output is `KeyError: 'Seen'`

Advice to this simple problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. I'm voting to close the question since ultimately it's a typo, `==` vs `=`, but don't worry, it happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rarebirds = {
    "Gold-crested Toucan": {
        "Height (m)": 1.1,
        "Weight (kg)": 35,
        "Aggressive": True
    },
    "Pearlescent Kingfisher": {
        "Height (m)": 0.25,
        "Weight (kg)": 0.5,
        "Aggressive": False,
    },
}

for key in rarebirds.keys():
    rarebirds[key]['Seen'] = False
```

1. Use `rarebirds.keys()` in the for loop to iterate over the keys.
2. You're doing `rarebirds[key]['Seen'] == False`. The double equals is trying perform an equality check which is causing the `keyError`.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!  I'd been chewing on that for days...

Comment: Iterating over a dict gives you the keys already, no need to use `dict.keys()`.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, you're right. It's just more clear when you explicitly write it.